# Need to find 2 strings using regex with multiple lines of text between them and insert replacement text

Tags: regex, python-2.7, replace

I need perform a regular expression find and replace, many times in a large html file.

The first string to find is the following:

```
(?-i)(<p class=.+\r\n.+)([\d]{2}/[\d]{2}/[\d]{4})(((.+\r\n)+?)(.+>))(MIR)
```

The second string to find is the next occurrence of:

> "Times New Roman"'>MIR

My objective is to insert the date group ([\d]{2}/[\d]{2}/[\d]{4}) into the second string, just before the "MIR"

My attempts to do this were unsuccessful.

The search string I came up with was this:

> (?-i)())(MIR)((.+\r\n)+?)((.+)?>)(MIR)

The replacement string I came up with was this:

> \1\2\3\7\8\10\2< br />\12

It does not work.

I need to do many such find and replace actions in the html file.

Any help you could give me would be much appreciated.

Marc

Comment: No need to encase `\d` inside `[]` unless you're adding something else to the character class that you may want matched.

Comment: By default case-insensitivity isn't applied. You don't need `(?-i)`.

Comment: This is pretty confusing. "The first string to find is the following": where is the actual source string? Please provide a minimal example with input string and desired result (and patterns you tried).

Comment: Sorry for posting my question in a confusing way.  I posted a minimal text file at this url: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8j7r1pcotrcrxz/2018-03-02_HtmlTextForStackOverflow.html?dl=0

Comment: I put the wrong search string in my original post.  The search string I used was the following:  (?-i)(<p class=.+\r\n.+)([\d]{2}/[\d]{2}/[\d]{4})(((.+\r\n)+?)(.+>))(MIR)((.+\r\n)+?)((.+)?>)(MIR)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like with the following pattern:

```
(<p class=.+\n.+)([\d]{2}/[\d]{2}/[\d]{4})(?:((.+\n)+?)(.+>))(MIR)
```

and substitution

```
\1\2\3\4\5\2< br />\6
```

Sample Code:

```
import re
regex = r"(<p class=.+\n.+)([\d]{2}/[\d]{2}/[\d]{4})(?:((.+\n)+?)(.+>))(MIR)"
subst = "\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\2< br />\\6"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/g1QKS2/1).

Comment: Your original pattern does only have 7 matching groups. I have removed the overlapping one with a non-capturing group.

Comment: STRING #1:
<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>05/13/2016<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  <p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>MIR

STRING #2 = Numerous lines of HTML code in which STRING #1 does not appear.
STRING #3 equals the quoted characters: ">MIR"

OBJECTIVE: Capture the date (05/13/2016) in STRING #1 into a group, and insert the date into STRING #3 between the > symbol and the MIR, as follows: >05/13/2016 MIR

Comment: Dear wp78de, your comment of 1 min. ago appeared just as I was posting my comment, which is incomprehensible because the line feeds are removed.  I'll post it as a file in a few minutes, i..e, as soon as I can get it done.

Comment: I uploaded a PDF file (which replied to wp78de's postings) at this url:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgjdzrvmpuv5wnm/2018-03-02%20%20%20Regex%20ques%2C%20reply%20to%20StackOverflow%20Help-Response%20from%20wp78de%20who%20posted%20a%20demo%20on%20Regex101.com%20.docx.PDF?dl=0

Comment: I uploaded a .txt version of the same file (which replied to wp78de's postings) at this URL:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jl4mrj7x481647d/2018-03-02%20%20%20Regex%20ques%2C%20reply%20to%20StackOverflow%20Help-Response%20from%20wp78de%20who%20posted%20a%20demo%20on%20Regex101.com%20.txt?dl=0

Comment: @user235218 this is not how SO usually works. Try this pattern instead: https://regex101.com/r/MAFCUg/2 and let me know if it does the trick.